# Отправка письма через функцию mail

Tags: php

Добрый день! Использую denwer. Посылаю письмо через функцию mail. Понятно, стоит заглушка sendmail (все мессаги скапливаются в /tmp/!sendmail - почтовый эмулятор). Как её отключить? Нужно узнать, получит ли письмо новый пользователь в реальных условиях, после публикации сайта на хостинге, или нет? Я хочу послать пробник на своё мыло, но работает заглушка!

Comment: Можете залить кусок кода из скрипта на любой бесплатный хостинг (какой? гугл в помощь) и проверить.

Answer (score 2):

В папочке `\usr\local\php5` лежит файл php.ini, в нем в разделе 
`[mail function]`:

> ;;
> ;; Комментарий Денвера:
> ;; чтобы отключить отладочный эмулятор sendmail, укажите в директиве SMTP
> ;; адрес SMTP-сервера вашего провайдера, а также НЕ ЗАБУДЬТЕ закомментировать
> ;; директиву `sendmail_path ниже`! Если `sendmail_path` не закомментировать,
> ;; работать не будет, т.к. `sendmail_path` имеет приоритет.
> ;;

Итого:

> ; For Win32 only.
> SMTP = smtp.yandex.ru
> smtp_port = 25
>
> ; For Win32 only.
> `sendmail_from = me@yandex.ru`
>
> ; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
> ; `sendmail_path = \usr\sbin\sendmail -t -i`

Answer (score 1):

Если письма обнаруживаются в папке sendmail, то они отправляются, можете быть спокойны. Другое дело, письма отправленные просто функцией mail без заголовков могут попасть в папку спам.